# Clion cannot resolve i after integer when <complex> library is included

Tags: c++, clion

Hi I am working with complex number and numeric computation a lot. I am new in C++. 
In Visual Studio 2015 the following code WORKS.

```
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    complex<double> a = 1.0 + 2i;
    cout << a << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

However in Clion this gives me error like this

```
35: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""i' complex<double> a = 1.0 + 2i;
```

Please help me. Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Different type, exact same issue. Read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i).

Comment: I change the code to the following
    #include <iostream>
#include <complex>


int main() {
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::complex<double> a = 1+1i;
    return 0;
}
It still didn't work.
The error are:
26: error: expected namespace name
    using namespace std::complex_literals;

Comment: Do you compile in C++14 mode? If not, please [edit] the question to include your updated [mcve] (good job on that btw) as well as your compiler, which compiler version you use and how you invoke it.

Comment: Erm, I meant you should edit the question if compiling in C++14 mode does not help, not the other way around. Sorry. Btw, apart from the wrong type of the first summand in your comment, that code appears to be correct and works in a C++14 compiler. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2961d3545111d98